# Uart on PIC16F690 and Bluetooth issue

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, microcontroller, uart, mikroc

I have spent so much time trying to get the UART to work with Bluetooth module. I am using PICkit 2 programmer to burn the code to [PIC16F690](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262E.pdf). When I use the UART tool, I can transmit and receive data correctly. I am able to echo whatever I am typing. When I connected the Bluetooth module to breadboard, I can receive the data being typed from UART tool to my phone. However, typing something from my phone does not echo it back.

So here is the summary

1. Transmit and Receive works on the UART Tool provided by PICkit 2 programmer
2. My phone can receive data from UART Tool. However transmitting from my phone -> Bluetooth -> PIC does not work. I have BC417 Bluetooth module. What could be the problem?

Here is my code

```
void UARTx_Read_Text(char *Output, char *Delimiter, char Attempts);
void UARTx_Write_Text(char * UART_text);
char UART_Data_Ready();



void main (){
unsigned char receive;

// Set all pins as digital
ANSEL = 0x00 ;
ANSELH = 0x00 ;

// Disable comparators
C1ON_bit = 0   ;
C2ON_bit = 0  ;

UART1_Init(9600); // initialize UART1 module
Delay_ms(5000);   // delay



UART1_Write_Text("TEST");
while (1) {

  if (UART1_Data_Ready())
  {
     receive = UART1_Read();
     UART1_Write(receive);

  }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "What could be the problem?" Anything, there is not enough information. Can you verify that there is serial data coming out from the bluetooth module? Have you tried the same code on some other UART device? Have you verified that your UART can handle the selected baudrate given the prescaler settings specific for your MCU and clock? Do you get any errors such as buffer overrun or framing errors? What's the UART signal setup, any handshaking?

Answer (score 0):

"from my phone -> Bluetooth -> PIC does not work"

So without any details of what is wrong,

I suggest you don't retransmit the bytes (due to the delays) but just count them and periodically transmit the total and see if that gives different symptoms.